# Nested statements unreachable code

Tags: java, nested

I am writing a program and I am having a difficult time getting the nested part correct. In my method I have to get the ith digit from a number which I can do just fine but if the ith digit is not in the number then I have to return -1. When I attempt to write this in it says that the code is unreachable. I have spent hours trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static int numDigits(int number)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while(number !=0)
    {
        int digit = number % 10;
        number= number /10;
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

public static int getDigit(int number, int i)
{
    int negative =0;
    int counter = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    while(counter < i)
    {
         digit = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        counter++;

    }   

    return digit;

    if(i>numDigits(number))
    {
        negative = -1;
    }
    return negative;
```

Comment: Because you hit `return digit;` and the rest of the code in that method cannot possibly ever execute. You need to *conditionally* return either `digit` or `negative`.

Comment: You have several errors: 1) a `return` should be the last line in a function to be executed. So everything that is after the `return` not be executed.
2) function: `getDigit (int number, int i)` the variable `number`  is changed within the `while` therefore `numDigists (int number)` function is not taking the original number.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help!! Jose by switching the two statements around everything worked like a charm!! I really appreciate everything you guys do!

Comment: Note that the solution of Mahdad and mine is not the same, there is a slight difference.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
    public static int numDigits(int number)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while(number !=0)
        {
            int digit = number % 10;
            number= number /10;
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public static int getDigit(int number, int i)
    {
        int negative =0;
        int counter = 0;
        int digit = 0;
        while(counter < i)
        {
             digit = number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
            counter++;

        }          

        if(i>numDigits(number))
        {
            negative = -1;
        return negative;
        }
        return digit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That took care of the unreachable code but now it will only return negative and not the digit when I test it. I must have something else wrong in my code.

Comment: @AmandaMerical :  when if(i>numDigits(number)) is true everytime return negative;
but when this line was false , your method return digit;

Comment: Its doing something weird. When I call getDigit(1254,1) it will print out 4, if I call getDigit(1254,2) it will print out 5, but when I call getDigit(1254,3) it prints out -1. I think it's because the number 3 is not actually in the number 1254 but the 1 and 2 are, it does the same thing I if call (1254,4) it prints out 1. If I change the numbers to something like 7896 it will always print -1. Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: Amanda, I would strongly recommend you try stepping through this with a debugger.  This will help you understand what's going on.